# Java: как скачать таблицу Google Spreadsheets в виде файла Excel?

Tags: java, excel, google-drive

Есть таблица с отчетами в Google SpreadSheets. Нужно получить из нее данные в приложении на Java - либо напрямую, если возможно, либо скачав эту таблицу в виде файла Excel и далее получить из него данные с помощью библиотеки Apache POI.

Мне больше нравится второй вариант, т.к. полученные данные тоже надо представить в виде файла Excel, т.е. Apache POI все равно будет подключена.

Вопрос: как скачать таблицу из Java программы? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 3):

Наиболее верный путь - начать с готовой библиотеки, которая решает эту задачу.

У Google Drive есть [Java-обертка](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java#prerequisites) над REST API, призванная снизить боль от ручной работы с API и OAuth-авторизацией (вы ведь наверняка не только общедоступные файлы хотите скачивать?).

Подробный пример объясняет как настроить клиентский `driveService`, после чего [скачивание файла](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file) сведется к нескольким строчкам кода:

```
String fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files()
    .export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот берем, например, эту [табличку](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GgQgWihR_YPMgCVhzZYeNJwyCRCHmeZSkkP1h6obFog/edit#gid=0).

Формат url простой: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id_table>/edit#gid=0`

Для приведенной выше таблице `id_table`: `1GgQgWihR_YPMgCVhzZYeNJwyCRCHmeZSkkP1h6obFog`

Для [скачивания](http://%20https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GgQgWihR_YPMgCVhzZYeNJwyCRCHmeZSkkP1h6obFog/export?format=xlsx) таблицы используете `url` с таким форматом: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id_table>/export?format=xlsx`

Теперь осталось сделать `GET` запрос с url для скачивания, и его содержимое сохранить в файл `Excel`.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
wget --no-check-certificate -O file_name.xlsx https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<id_table>/export?format=xlsx
```

Помогает решить проблему:

```
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```